# React re-rendering but not displaying correct component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Profile` component that should render different components depending on user action (a click of an a tag). I have the information being passed and the correct component's state being updated. However, when the `Profile` component is re-rendered, it still rendered the same component, not the newly selected one.

```
class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentComponent: 'sales'
    }

    this.changeComponent = this.changeComponent.bind(this);
  }

  changeComponent(component){
    console.log('You are trying to change component!');
    console.log(this);
    this.setState({currentComponent: component});
  }

  render(){
      let component;
      switch(this.state.currentComponent){
        case 'sales':
          component =  <Sales />;
          break;
        case 'income':
          component = <Income />;
        default:
          component =  <Sales />;
      }
      const menuItems = [
        {
          text: 'Sales'
        },
        {
          text: 'Team'
        },
        {
          text: 'Income'
        },
        {
          text: 'Edit'
        }
      ]
      console.log(this.state);
      return <div id="profileWrap">
        <div id="profileMenu">
          <NavMenu menuItems={menuItems} currentComponent={this.state.currentComponent} changeComponent={this.changeComponent}/>
        </div>
        {component}
      </div>
  }
}
```

And my `Sales` / `Income` components are just

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

class Sales extends Component {
  render(){
      return(<h1>This is Sales!</h1>)
  }
}

export default Sales;
```

with `Income` in place of `Sales`.

As you can see, inside of the `Profile` component, I am logging when I access that function along with what my worker thinks `this` is at that moment in time (both of which seem correct) and I am also logging the state out on re-render, which does show the correct state being used. Is it something with my switch statement?

***Edit***

After changing my switch statement to `if/elseif` statements, it all works. Why is it that the `switch` causes it not to update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `break` in your switch statement:

```
  switch(this.state.currentComponent){
    case 'sales':
      component =  <Sales />;
      break;
    case 'income':
      component = <Income />;
      break; // <-- need this here or will fall through to default.
    default:
      component =  <Sales />;
  }
```

Update: You can also avoid this whole thing by adding the components to your `menuItems` array.

```
 this.state = { currentComponent: <Sales /> }

 ...

 const menuItems = [
    {
      text: 'Sales'
      component: <Sales />
    },
    ...
  ]
```

Then in render: `{ this.state.currentComponent }`

Comment: Holy moses...that was a stupid mistake. Thanks for helping me catch it! In 5 min, I'll accept this as the answer!

Comment: np :) updated my answer.. probably don't need that switch statement / if else ladder at all.

Comment: That is actually crazy smart and I was wondering how I would go about doing that